# ASP.NET MVC 4 to authenticate via Windows Authentication from different Domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, windows-authentication

I am developing an MVC4 web app that currently uses Forms Authentication. My Development environment (local PC) is joined to DomainA and Testing to DomainB, while Production goes to DomainA. I point the development and testing instances of the app to DomainB and then Production to DomainA and everything works flawlessly.

Now I need to migrate to Windows Authentication, but I need to keep pointing my local instance to Domain B instead of authenticating automatically against Domain A (which is the one the computer is joined to).

Is there a way to perform this? I set `<identity impersonate="true" />` but still (in my local machine joined to Domain A) the browser takes users from Domain B as invalid and only validates those from Domain A, even when I specify the user as "DomainB\User" with its corresponding password.

Just to make sure: I don't want to keep a mixed authentication schema, I just want to be able to point to a certain Domain/AD to validate the users so I can keep debugging with the Testing users/groups (DomainB) instead of the Production ones (DomainA).

I also want to be able to log as another user to be able to debug the app with different roles and users as I do with Forms Auth.